# Obtaining Frequency of A Number for Each Sub-Heading

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two columns, one with people and times associated with those people, and one filled with 0s and 1s.  For any given person there is some associated combination of 0s and 1s.  We can determine the frequency with which 1s occur by taking the ratio of 1s to 0s for each individual and then placing this information beside the correct 'person header' to which the frequency information belongs.  How might one go about making a formula to do this sort of thing?  The data looks something like this:

```
A     B

John  1

Day 1 0 
Day 2 0 
Day 3 1
Day 4 0 
Day 5 0

Tim   2

Day 1 0
Day 5 1
Day 6 1

Jess  1

Day 2 0 
Day 3 1
```

The frequencies for John and Jess are clearly different, but the total number is the same, so the goal again is to create another column C that can use data from A and B to create the sub-heading summaries.

Comment: A pivot table is perfect for this type of analysis.

Comment: I think this data will be difficult to use a pivot table on since the data is structure for humans, not machines - that is, you need to read all the rows after a name until you find another row that doesn't start with "Day" (this is something you could do with VBA).  Pivot would work if you restructured your data to be more columns, (i.e. name, day, count), rather than having the name apply to the following days.

Comment: @ernie Agreed.  While wbeard52 is correct for the case I was originally considering there are other cases where knowing how to create a formula or macro for this will be useful.

Comment: I'm lost as to why you can't use SUM()? I can write it up for you in VBa but I'm struggling to understand it. Can I assume you want to programatically get the value (starting with John) 1, which is all of the days accumulated. Then, do the same for Tim and Jess. So, it's only those summed values you want to be added?

Comment: @Dave Not quite, I am looking to create a macro that, for a much larger list of customers, can look at column A, see that there is a name and note a date there, and then take the sum of column B out of the total number of dates that occur before the next name occurs.

Comment: AH.. is this because the list is big it would be too laborious to use SUM

Answer (score 0):

Use a SUMIF formula to sum the 0 and 1, divided by a COUNTIF formula to convert to an average. You need to use the version of SUMIF and COUNTIF which use 3 arguments because you want to sum a different range to the criteria range.

e.g. =SUMIF(A1:A100, "=Jess", C1:C100)